# Python not getting the result I expect from my Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
a = int(input("Age1: "))
b = int(input("Age2: "))
c = int(input("Age3: "))


def fix_age(index):
    if (index >= 13 and index < 15) or (index > 16 and index <= 19):
    index = 0
     
    

def filter_teens(a, b, c):
    fix_age(a)
    fix_age(b)
    fix_age(c)
    summ = a+b+c
    return print(summ)
filter_teens(a ,b ,c)
```

I am trying to change the one of the ages to zero if it is a number between 13 to 19 not including 16 and 15 can not make it, already lost my mind.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not returning values from `fix_age`. You need to also define the values you are returning in your function. For example: `def fix_age(index):` should return `index` and in your `filter_teens` method you need to assign calls to your functions as variables to use them....i.e. `a = fix_age(a)`

Comment: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: `fix_age()` is not altering the value of what it is passed. You probably want to return the corrected value in that function and do something more like `a = fix_age(a)`

Comment: @ViaTech is right, you need `fix_age` to `return` a value. There's also an indentation error in that function

Comment: @talp -- it looks like you updated your post that this is resolved.  Could you also mark an answer as "accepted" to indicate a solution worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

As the comments suggested you are not returning a value from your function which syntactically cannot work with what you are trying to do as you have posted your code.

The solution you are likely looking for is here, simply changing the `return` values of your functions:

**Note: I have added comments where I thought important to explain the code changes**

```
try:
    # FYI, this try catches most basically anything 
    # entered that isn't a number/int
    a = int(input("Age1: "))
    b = int(input("Age2: "))
    c = int(input("Age3: "))
except Exception as ex:
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    print('Error with initialization :', ex)


def fix_age(index):
    # as the try-catch catches int errors above, hitting
    # issues here seems less likely, plus we catch the calls below.
    if (index >= 13 and index < 15) or (index > 16 and index <= 19):
        index = 0

    # you must return this value from the function if you want to
    # use it logically, there are other ways to use the return of
    # a function as a variable, but this is likely easiest to understand
    # as a new programmer
    return index


def filter_teens(a, b, c):
    # simply catch all calls to see if there are issues, and show them
    try:
        a_fixed = fix_age(a)
    except Exception as a_ex:
        print('error with a', a_ex)
        a_fixed = 0
    try:
        b_fixed = fix_age(b)
    except Exception as b_ex:
        print('error with b', b_ex)
        b_fixed = 0
    try:
        c_fixed = fix_age(c)
    except Exception as c_ex:
        print('error with c', c_ex)
        c_fixed = 0
    summ = a_fixed + b_fixed + c_fixed
    return summ  # smarter to return this val and use it where needed


# print out the call as we are only returning from filter_teens now
print(filter_teens(a, b, c))
```

Overall the issue was that, based on my take of your posted code, you were expecting function calls to be 'magical'... haha they are, but they normally need to be assigned to values to use them in other methods/functions as the call is being placed, this is what I am showing.

In my use, I think of functions as pieces of code that operate logic for the app (in your case by altering variables to be used elsewhere). For that to work in your case, you need to pass `return` values back from your function logic so it can be used where the values are needed/accessed.

Comment: i tried to print it out but i got a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Comment: @talp did you fix your `fix_age()` method first?

Comment: @JonSG yeah i got it fixed all of it

Comment: I have added `try-except` to catch random issues with input. Can you show your input if this doesn't work for you? My catch clauses are generic, basically catching everything and providing `0` values if an error occurs, so I am curious what you are entering to cause an issue if it persists.

Comment: @talp where you state "but i got a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType`'". Based on your updated question that was likely happening because you are returning a `print()` statement. You need that (initially, before my changes) to be `return summ` not, `return print(summ)`, but your intial question is still missing variable assignments

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, func `fix_age()` has incorrect code. You should add 4 spaces before `index = 0` because python flow-control clauses rely on spaces.

```
def fix_age(index):
    if (index >= 13 and index < 15) or (index > 16 and index <= 19):
        index = 0
```

Secondly, you can't change variable in this case. You should return new value and apply it to the variable. And thirdly, if you want to print variable, you must return `summ`, not clause `print(summ)`.

```
a = int(input("Age1: "))
b = int(input("Age2: "))
c = int(input("Age3: "))


def fix_age(index):
    if (index >= 13 and index < 15) or (index > 16 and index <= 19):
        index = 0
    return index
def filter_teens(a, b, c):
    a = fix_age(a)
    b = fix_age(b)
    c = fix_age(c)
    summ = a+b+c
    return summ
print(filter_teens(a ,b ,c))
```

Comment: Yes, essentially identical